# Start downloading zip automatically which was made by Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a button which let server make zip file by Ajax.

```
$('.zipButton').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).context.firstChild.data);
    $(this).context.firstChild.data = "working......";


    $(this).addClass('disabled');
    var self = $(this);

    $.post('{{path('acme_member_zip')}}',// make zip file on server.
        function(response){
            if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
                console.log(response.message);  
                self.context.firstChild.data = "finish make zip";
                alert("please download http://www.myserver.com/myzip/arc.zip");             
            }   
            else {console.log("no correct return");} 
        }, "json");
});
```

For now, after making zip I let user know where the zip file by alert.

However,I want to push on browser start downloading automatically.
How can I make it???

Comment: redirect to php file with this function http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php

Comment: As I know you cannot send the zip file in ajax response, so what you could do is to reload the page and change the content type of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few way to achieve this.

1)
you can use the `download` attribute in the hyperlink

`<a href="your file path" download id="download">Your file Name</a>`

`document.getElementById('download').click();`

2)
Use the jQuery file Download plugin
https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

3)
Set `window.location = 'your file path';` after the success

Comment: I have never heard of download attribute. it must be useful. and way 3 is also nice. thank you for giving me nice three answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the client to the ZIP url with `document.location`, like this :

```
$.post('{{path('acme_member_zip')}}',// make zip file on server.
    function(response){
        if(response.code == 100 && response.success){
            console.log(response.message);  
            self.context.firstChild.data = "finish make zip";
            document.location = "http://www.myserver.com/myzip/arc.zip";         
        }   
        else {
            console.log("no correct return");
        } 
    }, 
    "json"
);
```

Comment: Thank you , the problem is very simple. I understood.